# Angularjs transclude specific content

Tags: angularjs, directive

The 'accordion' directive which comes with ui.bootstrap is able to get title data from the 'accordion-heading' element. The rest of the content renders as accordion body. I want to do something like that with my directive.

How can I achieve this in angular?

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your title : Use **angular directive transclude**

In your directive definition, set `transclude` to true. Then you will be able to use `ng-transclude` in your template to say where to put the transcluded content.

Take a look at : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Comment: Simply placing ng-transclude will include all of the content in that single div. But that is not the case with 'accordion' directive. It takes the 'accordion-heading' element and places it in the header while rest of the content is placed in body